# Enrolling Anonymous Users in Engagement Plans

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

I know that it is possible to enroll users in an engagement plan from with Sitecore by adding them to a specific state in the plan when they visit a campaign URL, adding them when they submit a Web Forms for Marketers Form, and manually adding them in the Supervisor interface.

Additionally, I know that you can use the API to add a user as described here:
http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/programming-for-sitecore-dms-engagement-plans/

However, that method requires a username.

I would like to enroll anonymous users in an engagement plan when they visit any page represented by a particular template in Sitecore (ie, page from the Product template). Is this possible using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Sitecore support, this is not currently possible. However, I was able to achieve what I wanted by adding a jQuery AJAX call to the campaign URL to the sublayout used by the page type in question. Naturally this only works for clients with JS enabled, but for my purposes, that is not an issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function() { $.get('/?sc_camp=[campaignid]'); });</script>
```

**Edited 2014-05-19**

I found a way to do this via the Sitecore API. This is rough and needs to check for null values, exceptions, etc., but it *does* work:

```
string cookieVal = Request.Cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"].Value;
List<Guid> guids = new List<Guid>() {
    new Guid(cookieVal)
};
Guid automationStateId = new Guid("{24963AE9-1C8C-4E18-8EEE-01BC249D1F1B}");
Guid automationId = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(automationStateId)).ParentID.ToGuid();
Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.AutomationManager.Provider.CreateAutomationStatesFromBulk(guids, automationId, automationStateId);
```

Comment: You could also do something server side to redirect all requests to pages with that template to their equivalent with the query string added. That would remove the need for javascript.

Comment: Nice suggestion TwentyGotoTen!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my above comment, and to supplement your own answer, here's a processor that you could add to the after the `ItemResolver` in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline that would achieve the desired result. It is a very basic version that you could embellish as you see fit

```csharp
class CampaignRedirect
{
    public void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        // must not already have the querystring in the URL         
        if(request.QueryString["sc_camp"] != null &&
            request.QueryString["sc_camp"] != "XXXXXXXX")
            return;

        // must have a context item
        if(Sitecore.Context.Item == null)
            return;

        var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;

        // must be the right template
        if(item.TemplateID.ToString() != "{XXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX}")
            return;

        var basicUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);

        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Redirect(basicUrl + "?sc_camp=XXXXXXX");
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with adding processors, take a look [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Media/Prevent%20Files%20from%20Uploading/Pipeline%20upload/Second%20example.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - that's a good solution that doesn't rely on ISAPI_Rewrite or IIS URL Rewrite, so it would work for folks who can't/don't want to add those to the mix. The only reason I'm not going it this way is that I don't want to have the ?sc_camp=whatever appended to all the URLs for the pages. But ... it seems like we could grab the DMS session cookies and their values and construct a new HTTP request to the URL in the processor, and achieve the same result as my AJAX request idea, and then it would work for the few people who have JS turned off.

Comment: Sure. Your solution is perfectly valid. I just live in the past, and always try to come up with a non-JS way first :-)